# How do you sync the code behind when updating a user control using javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, .net-4.0

I have a custom user control that serves as a reusable `ASP` `DropDownList` that asynchronously retrieves data from an `RESTful` endpoint

```
<myControls:AjaxDropDown ID="ddlDropdown" runat="server" ServicePath="/MyWebService2.asmx/GetLetterTypes"/>
```

Inside the user control, I'm updating the drop down content via success in `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: $('#<%=textBoxUrlPath.ClientID %>').val(),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  async: true,
  success: function(res) {
    onGetLetterTypesSuccess(res);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

How do I sync the data retrieved by `$.ajax` with the code behind for the user control?

The reason I'm using `$.ajax` rather than doing a partial update via the `UpdatePanel` control is due UpdatePanel's inability to have multiple asynchronous calls at a time on a single page.

Comment: Do you mean: "how do I update the drop down list entries int he drop down list control with data fetched via the ajax call"?

Comment: @Jonathan Not necessarily. My ultimate goal is for the code behind for a Page to access the selected content of the asp:DropDownList. However, since I'm updating this drop down list via the client side javascript, the code behind/viewstate wouldn't have a reference to that information as part of the page life cycle.

Comment: Oh I see. And this is webforms, I guess? If it is MVC, then the value in the dropdown is passed to the controller and, even if the values are updated client side after page load, they would be mapped to the viewmodel when it comes back to the controller

Comment: @Jonathan Yep this is webforms. I wish I could use MVC since it's a lot simpler to do the task but my current situation doesn't allow for it unfortunately.

Comment: I think you're discovering that Web Forms does not play nicely if you stray outside of its sandbox, such as loading some data via custom AJAX. Unfortunately for you, you're just going to hit more and more of these ridiculous problems the more sophisticated you make your application. Is there any possibility you could ditch Web Forms, or at least in this case ditch the need to do a postback?

Comment: @mason I agree, I'm going to see if I can ditch the need to do a postback in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to not go this route of client side updating, since it's directly opposing the Web Form structure. Instead I'll settle for a synchronous solution of make this call from the code behind and populating the DropDownList before serving the Page.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use asp.net hidden fields to store the selected values but yes it could become unnecessarily cumbersome through client side.